# Notify clients whenever data is updated in the database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have a SQL Server database on our main system. I have more than 100 clients accessing the global database.

In this, I need to fire an event from the SQL database to all clients (more than 100) whenever any client updates, inserts or deletes any data in the database.

Main purpose this fire event will be used for updating `DataGridView` in all clients.

Comment: use trigger to accomplish you task.

Comment: By using Trigger, it will through event to all client c# application?

Comment: this seems to me to be the wrong way to handle the situation. You could end up with the clients datagridviews updating far too many times to be usable. Would it not be better to come from the front end and simply refresh the data every couple of minutes?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - perhaps I'm misunderstanding but surely by triggering the update to a datagridview whenever an update / delete / insert occurs on the database from any client you could end up with this effectively happening much more than every couple of minutes.

Comment: First the question is too broad for StackOverflow. You have a page with grid view and the data in this grid view can be changed from other users. Just DataBind() the grid on every page open ...

Comment: @sr28: You are right. I think it depends on how often the data set changes.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't know why you think it is not asp.net. There is no tag and also it is not written in the question. There are asp.net webforms and winforms. He just wrote (C# form) ...

Comment: @mybirthname: Okay, might be my misinterpretation.

Comment: @mybirthname: Asked OP. Question updated.

Comment: @PatrickHofman in this case like you said, when he opens the form take the new DataSource-> There is no need to kill a bird with a tank. This is just my opinion :)

Comment: @mybirthname: Don't want to argue too long about this, but in the case of a stock broking system, this functionality is very useful.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you are correct, if you must have the right data on the second. I doubt this is the case, but whatever your solution is good.

Comment: You best bet is to add a timer and pull every x seconds from Db.

Comment: I think this boils down to how up to date does the data need to be? Does it need to be as close to real time as possible? If not then how often do you want to refresh the data the clients can see? Coupled with this is how often is the data likely to be changed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the notifications provided by the [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the behind [SQL Server Notification Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166495%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

You might want to read up on this subject on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) how to use `SqlDependency` and its events.

What is basically does:

1. You execute a command, stating you want to know when the result of that query changes;
2. The database registers your request and checks if the data changes;
3. If it does, it notifies your client and you can get the new data.

Comment: can you please is there any sample code for SqlDependency because I am new to SQL Server...

Comment: Yes. Click on the first link in my answer.